# Highcharts Treemap : set a maximum level visibility

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

I'm displaying a treemap with 4 levels.
For visibility purpose, I only want level 1 and 2 to be visible. I'm allowing drill to node, so I want this to be applicable when zooming in.

Is there some settings to apply to the plotOptions or to the data, like an opacity but for the levels ?

([here is my chart](http://jsfiddle.net/3tegwsa0/) with Highcharts' demo data, so there is no lvl 4...)

```
plotOptions: {
  treemap : {
    allowDrillToNode: true,  
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,                      
    dataLabels: {
      allowOverlap: false,
      enabled: false      
    },
    drillUpButton: {
      position: { 
        align: 'left',
        x: 5,
        y: 5
      },
      text: "< Back"
    },  
    interactByLeaf: false,
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    layoutStartingDirection: 'horizontal', 
    levelIsConstant: false,
    levels: [{          
      level: 1,         
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'left',
        backgroundColor: "black",
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}',   
        style: {
          fontSize: "10px",
          color: "white",
          "fontWeight": "normal",
          textOutline: false
        },           
        useHTML: false,                                    
        verticalAlign: 'top'
      },                     
      borderWidth: 6,
    },
             {          
               level: 2,  
               borderWidth: 3,
             }],
    states: {
      hover: {
        borderColor: '#FFEE00',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's focus on this simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/83ybtLxs/ what would you like to hide?

Comment: I've made a little update for A2 sub-level : http://jsfiddle.net/0sr3ovhk/. What I want to hide is A21 and A22, but when clicking on A, A21 and A22 shoud become visible. A2 has its own color, so its color should be displayed instead of sub-levels A21 and A22.

Comment: something like is done here? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u3rh16mq/